# seeing different shape and size buttons on design screen and virtual machine why?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I tried to design some Buttons. 
On the design screen they look as I want them to.
After I try to see on the emulator, the sizes and shapes are smaller than design screen.

I want to get the same shape and size on the emulator.

Please help me

How can I this?

Here is the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_above="@+id/socialMediaButtons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageButton
                android:src="@drawable/buton"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

            <ImageButton
                android:src="@drawable/buton"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageButton
                android:src="@drawable/buton"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <ImageButton
                android:src="@drawable/buton"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageButton
                android:src="@drawable/buton"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <ImageButton
                android:src="@drawable/buton"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageButton
                android:src="@drawable/buton"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <ImageButton
                android:src="@drawable/buton"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:id="@+id/btn8"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/socialMediaButtons"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnFb"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTw"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Check or Android API level in your design screen set same as your AVD. Also check your screen size of AVD and in Designer

Comment: Share screenshots of both. It might be related to different API levels as @Sarz has mentioned.